# Rendering props.children with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Could someone please explain why I have to have "props.children" wrapped in a "div" for react-router to work.

This works:

```
export default (props) => {
        return (
            <div id="main-template">
                {props.children}
            </div>
        );
}
```

However, this doesn't:

```
export default (props) => {
        return (
                {props.children}
        );
}
```

Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: see relevant info from [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have one child node you don't need wrap `props.children` to `{}`, you can just return `props.children`

```
const Component = (props) => {
    return props.children;
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/ct74pezm/2/)

if you have more than one node, for instance

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

you **must** wrap `children` to one root element, because component must return only one root element, you can not return several, like this

```
return (
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

JSX transforms the HTML-looking code into javascript function calls. Returning multiple top level components

```
return (
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
);
```

gets transformed into

```
return (
    React.createElement('p', null, 'text'),
    React.createElement('p', null, 'text'),
    React.createElement('p', null, 'text')
);
```

which isn't valid. Since you need to return a single value, you can't have multiple top level elements rendered. The React team has been trying to figure out how to handle this well, but there isn't a solution currently.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have `props.children` wrapped in a div. The issue here is that you are incorrectly utilizing the parentheses on the `return` statement. The opening and closing parentheses is done whenever we have a multiline jsx block.

In your case, you do not have a multiline jsx, in fact yours is a single line javascript expression so you can just do this:

```
export default (props) => {
        return props.children;
}
```

Why no curly braces? Because you do not have any jsx in there. The curly braces are only for when you want to inject JavaScript variables into jsx.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please explain why I have to have "props.children" wrapped in a "div" for react-router to work.

This is not a React Router or a `props.children` issue. React requires a collection of elements ("children") to be wrapped by a parent element.

**There are several solutions:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```
<Fragment>{props.children}</Fragment>
```

```
<>{props.children}</>
```

```
<div>{props.children}</div>
```